# Why are the links in my About section not working as on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks, profile-sync

- I wrote my *About* section on **Stack Overflow**.
- When I interacted with **Meta Stack Exchange** the first time, it asked if I wanted to **sync** the info from the first accounts. I said "yes".
- That synchronized my *About* section too, except:
  What are **links** (hyperlinks) on my *About* section on **Stack Overflow**, display as *plain text* on Meta.

I tried editing it on Meta **directly**, but, though in **edit** mode they showed correctly (meaning blue and hyperlinked), after saving and viewing from the front-end, they were back to *plain text*.

How can I fix that?

> **Note:** (posted after - and based on - the accepted answer, to clarify the question **and** the answer)
>   I *did* have enough reputation score on **Stack OverFlow** for links to display as such at the time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have enough reputation. Users below 10 reputation cannot have hyperlinks in their profiles, which is simply a way to prevent spammers from creating profiles with a bunch of links and getting them indexed by search engines. Any links they include in their about me, as well as the "Website Link" field which shows up to the right, do not actually get linked until they reach the 10 reputation threshold.

Comment: **Note to readers:** I *do* have enough reputation on **Stack OverFlow**, hence the different outcome.