# Get backlink Stack Exchange for SEO

Tags: discussion, seo, search-indexing

Can securing a backlink by inserting a link in the Stack Exchange profile have a good effect on [DR/DA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_authority) (domain rating and domain authority) [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)?

Stack Exchange has a very high score for DR/DA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['rel=nofollow' in Profile links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327588/rel-nofollow-in-profile-links) - tl;dr only after you have 2k rep

Comment: Practically speaking... how much value is there? Especially since to some extent, 'weakening' the value of these things feels like a necessary thing to discourage spammers trying to 'improve' their SEO...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the ['rel=nofollow' in Profile links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327588/11107541) post on Meta Stack Overflow, according to old meta posts, if you have below 2k rep, links on your profile will have `nofollow` on them:

> The idea is that *without* the [`nofollow`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow), the Stack Overflow profile page counts as a link to the target website in Google's PageRank algorithm (and similar algorithms in other search engines). So if you are an established user, you can use that fact to improve the SEO of your website just a little bit.
>
> The threshold for this privilege is [2000 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11358/295232), but it is not mentioned in the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).
>
> - [@Glorfindel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173)

This is also mentioned in [this answer to "*What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55860/997587), and [this answer by Jeff to "*The 'nofollow' attribute is set in user profile website link... why?*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55843/997587). This includes the website link field, the twitter field, github field, etc., but does not include links in the about me field.

And if you have below 10 rep, links on your profile are not wrapped in anchor tags and are just regular text.

[Why are the links in my About section not working as on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268960/997587)

> Users below 10 reputation cannot have hyperlinks in their profiles, which is simply a way to prevent spammers from creating profiles with a bunch of links and getting them indexed by search engines. Any links they include in their about me, as well as the "Website Link" field which shows up to the right, do not actually get linked until they reach the 10 reputation threshold. - [@animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)

And from animuson's answer to [What is the policy on destroying users with very spammy profiles but have not posted spam yet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297993/997587):

> We already have rules in place on the system that prevents links in their profile from actually becoming links until they reach 10 reputation anyways. While some crawlers will still follow things that look like links (even in text), having them as plain text prevents our page rank or any kind of endorsement from passing along to it, and it's unlikely the crawler will actually index anything wherever it ends up. - [@animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)

Comment: Interesting because links in [my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand?tab=profile) have `nofollow` and I definitely reached 2K. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand yeah i'm just quoting old answers on meta sites. Not sure how accurate they are. I also checked out some other >2k users on stack overflow and also see that they have `nofollow` on their about me links...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I checked your profile out. Your profile's link doesn't have nofollow, but custom html link has nofollow.

Comment: Okay, sorry, it took me a minute to understand what's happening here (and I may have even checked out source code to be sure). The _only_ link that has `nofollow` removed at 2K rep is the one called "[Website link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNYtt.png)" that appears in [the main byline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrZqx.png) of your profile (and any links to stack). From some of the descriptions on meta and elsewhere, it isn't clear that this is differentiated from links I throw into my profile text. One _could_ argue that those should get the same treatment, but not a battle I'm invested in.

Comment: So, for clarity, it's not "links on your profile" it is "links in your profile that point to stack (e.g. a usercard), and the link you provide in specific profile form fields (Website link, twitter, etc)" or something along those lines. Just "links on your profile" certainly implies that links in the about me text would benefit, and that is not the case.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks so much for digging. I just updated this post.